finding a function-parameter for other function that would make it fit the data
I have two vectors [f(x1), f(x2),...,f(xk})] and [g(x1, n(x1)), g(x2, n(x2)),..., g(xk, n(xk))] and x-vector = [x1, x2,.., xk]
I f and g are known functions, but function n(x) is unknown, I need to find such function n(x) so difference between f-vector and g-vector would be minimized.
I've searched through a few minimizing algoriths in scipy but all of them are returning a constant value and I need a function.
The only restrictions for n(x) is to be continious + n(x) returns a complex values
I found one way to solve it with newton method. I can found a constant value n_0 that would estimate n(x) with physics formula and give it as x_0 for scipy.optimize.newton(f(x_1) - g(x_1, n(x)), x_0 = n_0)(result will be noted as n_1), then I use a loop going through x-verctor with newton method with x_0 = result from previous step.
But i'm interested if there is a less complicated and more stable method

the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example
